# Map<String, Repository> Unexpected beheaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, hashmap

I'm trying to define a Map<String, DataTablesRepository> to map more than one JPA repository. This is my code

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyDataTablesService {

    private final RegistroDtRepository registroDtRepository;
    private final ContinentiDtRepository continentiDtRepository;

    public Map<String, DataTablesRepository> repositories = this.createMap();

    public DataTablesOutput<?> findAllDatatable(String repoId, DataTablesInput input) {

        System.out.println(this.repositories);

        DataTablesRepository repository = this.repositories.get(repoId);

        DataTablesOutput<?> res = repository.findAll(input);
        return res;
    }

    private Map<String, DataTablesRepository> createMap(){
        Map<String, DataTablesRepository> myMap = new HashMap<String, DataTablesRepository>();
        myMap.put("continenti", this.continentiDtRepository);
        myMap.put("registro", this.registroDtRepository);
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

Calling the findAllDataTable method, the expected output should be something like this

```
{registro=org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryImpl@2aec0c10, continenti=org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryImpl@1bf71fb7}
```

Instead, in terminal, i have this:

```
{registroDtRepository=org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryImpl@2aec0c10, continentiDtRepository=org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryImpl@1bf71fb7}
```

So the map keys are not setted properly and, of course, this.repositories.get("continenti") returns null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this really all of your code? There is no constructor and I suspct you have some annotations on there including Lombok ones.

Comment: @M.Deinum Right, I've added the annotations

Comment: Answered the question with some more information on what is happening, why and how to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can explicitly set the desired keys when creating the map:
here is the code to Initialize repositories map directly in the constructor:

```
private final Map<String, DataTablesRepository> repositories;

public MyDataTablesService(RegistroDtRepository registroDtRepository, ContinentiDtRepository continentiDtRepository) {
    this.registroDtRepository = registroDtRepository;
    this.continentiDtRepository = continentiDtRepository;

    this.repositories = createMap();
}


// and the rest of your code
```

Comment: Ok, solved removing the @AllArgsConstructor and using this constructor. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

And after your edit your problem is quite obvious (at least to a Spring user).

You are using `@AllArgsConstructor` which will generate a 3 argument constructor. It will create one like the one below.

```java
public MyDataTablesService(RegistroDtRepository registroDtRepository, ContinentiDtRepository continentiDtRepository, Map<String, DataTablesRepository> repositories) {
    this.registroDtRepository = registroDtRepository;
    this.continentiDtRepository = continentiDtRepository;
    this.repositories = repositories;
}
```

As there is only 1 single constructor Spring will automatically use this for autowiring. The `Map<String, ?>` is a special case for dependency injection, it will inject a `Map` with all the dependencies of the requested type `DataTablesRepository` with the name of the bean as the key.

> Even typed `Map` instances can be autowired as long as the expected key type is `String`. The map values contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys contain the corresponding bean names, as the following example shows:

The above quote is from the [Spring Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired.html)

To fix this you would need to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` which will create a constructor for with 2 arguments (the `final` fields) and leave everything else untouched. However this will still not work as the `createMap` is going to be called **before** the object has been constructed. To fix this you could use an `@PostConstruct` to initialize the `Map`.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyDataTablesService {

    private final RegistroDtRepository registroDtRepository;
    private final ContinentiDtRepository continentiDtRepository;

    public Map<String, DataTablesRepository> repositories = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void fillMap(){
        this.repositories.put("continenti", this.continentiDtRepository);
        repositories.put("registro", this.registroDtRepository);
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

A final option would be to annotate your repositories explicitly with `@Repository("<name-to-use-for-lookup")` and stick with the `@AllArgsConstructor` or make the `Map` final as well. That way Spring will take care of the injection with the proper names.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyDataTablesService {

    private final RegistroDtRepository registroDtRepository;
    private final ContinentiDtRepository continentiDtRepository;
    private final Map<String, DataTablesRepository> repositories;

    public DataTablesOutput<?> findAllDatatable(String repoId, DataTablesInput input) {

        System.out.println(this.repositories);

        DataTablesRepository repository = this.repositories.get(repoId);

        DataTablesOutput<?> res = repository.findAll(input);
        return res;
    }
}
```

This will need the following on your `RegistroDtRepository` (and ofcourse the `ContinentiDtRepository` with the proper name).

```java
@Repository("registro")
public interface RegistroDtRepository extends DataTablesRepositoryImpl {}

@Repository("continenti")
public interface ContinentiDtRepository extends DataTablesRepositoryImpl {}
```

This will register it with the proper name.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is *autowiring* `Map<String, DataTablesRepository> repositories` so, after spring injection, `repositories` gets overwritten.